# $sent_http_ variables disappear in Nginx in some circumstances

Tags: nginx, web-server, http-headers

I face a strange issue with Nginx. This is a minimal config that reproduce the error:

```
server {
    server_name     mydomain.com;
    listen          111.111.111.111:80;
    root            /some/path;

    set     $some_var   $sent_http_content_type;
    add_header  "X-Debug" $sent_http_content_type;
}
```

In this case `X-Debug` header is never shown in the response. But, if I comment this line:

```
set     $some_var   $sent_http_content_type;
```

everything works. It seems very strange to me because this line doesn't reassign the `$sent_http_content_type` var, but only reads.

It looks like it belongs to `$sent_http_` variables only.

I also tried `"${sent_http_content_type}"` instead of `$sent_http_content_type` with the same result.

`more_set_headers` directive doesn't fix this.

Why does Nginx behave like this? Is this a bug?

***Edit:***
The example I have provided is just the simpest case where `$sent_http_` vars desappear. In fact I want to do something like this:

```
if ($sent_http_access_control_allow_origin ~ "^(https?)://([^/]+)") {
    set $new_cors http://$1.$2.proxy.mydomain.com;
}
more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $new_cors";
```

I write a proxy server and I need to replace `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, because otherwise proxied sites don't work as expected.

In the above example `if` condition (in `server` section) never yields `true`, even if there is such header and it fits my regular expression.

Can this be fixed? Appreciate your help!

Comment: `if` directive also executed too early for you purpose.

Comment: @AlexeyTen does this mean that it's impossible to replace response header with regex?

Comment: It's possible. I'll edit answer

Comment: It would be a lot easier to use Lua module for example. Also, probably you should use `$upstream_http_*` variables.

Comment: I've updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx's `rewrite` module (where variables and `set` directive belongs) is quite non-intuitive and fragile. But, actually

```
set     $some_var   $sent_http_content_type;
```

is meaningless anyway because `set` directive is executed at the beginning of request and there is no `$sent_http_*` variables available at the moment.

What you could do (if you really want to use `$sent_http_*` variables somehow) is to use `map` directive.

```
map $sent_http_content_type $some_var {
    default $sent_http_content_type;
}

...
server {
    ...
    add_header "X-Debug"  $sent_http_content_type;
    add_header "X-Debug2" $some_var;
}
```

EDIT: Your problem could be solved with some more `map`s, but it would be a lot easier if you could use Lua module.

Here how it could be done with `map`s: (quite unreadable and unmaintainable)

```
map $sent_http_access_control_allow_origin $__proto {
    default "NONE";
    "~^(?<_>https?):" "$_";
}

map $sent_http_access_control_allow_origin $__host {
    default "";
    "~^https?://(?<_>[^/]+)" "$_";
}

map "http://$__proto.$__host.proxy.mydomain.com" $new_cors {
    default "";
    "~^http://NONE" "";
    "~^(?<_>.+)$" "$_";
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for the explanation! However `map` directive doesn't solve my real issue. Please see my edit. Is it possible to achieve what I want? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Your last `map` solution is a bit twisted but it **does work**. Thanks again, @AlexeyTen!